# How to search for a word (exact match) within a string?

Tags: python, string, search

I am trying to substring search

```
>>>str1 = 'this'
>>>str2 = 'researching this'
>>>str3 = 'researching this '

>>>"[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]" in str2
False

>>>"[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]" in str3
False
```

I wanted to True when looking in str3. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want Python's [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\sthis\s") # \s is whitespace
>>> # OR
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\Wthis\W")
>>> # \w is a word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_]), \W is anything but a word character
>>> str2 = 'researching this'
>>> str3 = 'researching this '
>>> bool(regex.search(str2))
False
>>> regex.search(str3)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10044e8b8>
>>> bool(regex.search(str3))
True
```

I have a hunch you're actually looking for the word "this", not "this" with non-word characters around it.  In that case, you should be using the word boundary escape sequence [`\b`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use regular expressions, but you are using ordinary string methods. You need to use the methods in the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re
>>> re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str2)
>>> re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str3)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000006C69370>
```

Comment: Thanks. if I want to search 'researching' using `re.search("[^a-z]"+'researching'+"[^a-z]", str3)`, I am not getting any object value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pradeep see the part in my answer referring to `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `in` does a regex search.

Take a look at the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do, but if you want to know if "this" is in "researching this", do:

```
"this" in "researching this"
```

(or)

```
str1 in str3
```

Or if you're trying to find it as an entire word only, do:

```
"this" in "researching this".split()
```

The result is that it will split "researching this" into `["researching", "this"]` and then check for the exact word "this" in it. So, this is False:

```
"this" in "researching thistles".split()
```

Comment: I think the idea is to account for word boundaries to ensure that an exact match is found (e.g., `str1 in "researching thistles"` should return `False`).

Answer (score 0):

For regular expressions in Python, use the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str2) is not None
False
>>> re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str3) is not None
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str1 = 'this'
str2 = 'researching this'
str3 = 'researching this '

if re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str2):
    print "found!"

if re.search("[^a-z]"+str1+"[^a-z]", str3):
    print "found!"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `re` module. `re` module is the one that you should use. `re` rocks.